# Parallel processing taking longer than serial processing & skipping to process few entries

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Why is parallel processing slower than serial processing in Python?**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import time
from functools import partial
import multiprocessing as mp

def print_hello(i, typ):
    print(typ + " : PID-" + str(os.getpid()) + "\n")
    # print("Hello World " + str(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N= mp.cpu_count()
    parallel_start_time = time.time()
    with mp.Pool(processes = N) as p:
        p.map(partial(print_hello,typ="Parallel"), (x for x in range(100)))
    parallel_end_time = time.time()
    

    serial_start_time = time.time()
    for x in range(100):
        print_hello(x, "Serial")
    serial_end_time = time.time()
    
    print("Parallel processing took " + str(parallel_end_time - parallel_start_time) + " seconds")
    print("Serial processing took " + str(serial_end_time - serial_start_time) + " seconds")
```

I wrote the output from the above script to a text file and below is the final output

```
./test_parallel.py > pid.txt
```

> ```
> 61 Parallel : PID-28311
>  Parallel processing took 0.11675715446472168 seconds
> 100 Serial : PID-28310
>  Serial processing took 0.0001430511474609375 seconds
> ```

**I also don't understand why python didn't processing 39 ids when using parallel processing**

Comment: sub-processes aren't guaranteed to run in any particular order, so there's a good chance the print lines for parallel processes 62-100 are actually above the print line for the 61st process in your example.

Comment: Add something crazy before `print(typ + " : PID-" + str(os.getpid()) + "\n")`, like `_ = 11 ** 100000`, and parallel will be faster.

Comment: When benchmarking parallel processing, make sure to *do* some actual processing. Just the added function calls of ``p.map(partial(`` mean the "parallel" version is doing three times as much work *before* actually running anything. Since the payload does practically nothing, that overhead is disproportionately costly.

Comment: All 100 parallel and serial processing occurs when I run you code. The slowness of the latter is due to the overhead of creating additional Python interpreter tasks.

Comment: @KacperFloriański: Your suggestion works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In multiprocessing, you also need to take *overhead* of creating processes in account. In this example, each process is doing a very small task i.e. printing a single statement. Therefore, the *overhead* will be quite significant which is why you are getting such results.

Multiprocessing is recommended in **CPU bound** (computation heavy) tasks. But, here it is **NOT** the case. Therefore, you should try it on some other example.

Comment: I added the line `_i = i ** 100000` to my function and I can see the parallel is a lot faster than serial. Thanks for the suggestion guys!